# Overlay text on video with MLT

Tags: mlt, melt-framework

My question is similar to [Adding text to videos using MLT Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33046841/270511) but I am using a different command.

My command is:

```
melt SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4 -attach watermark:title.txt producer.bgcolor=transparent in=50 out=500
```

This produces the text in title.txt overlaid on top of the original clip, but in a box with a black background.

```
melt -query filters
```

shows that I have the dynatext filter installed, but not pango.

How can I achieve my desired effect with the dynatext filter instead?

Answer (score 1):

`melt SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4 -attach dynamictext:"Some text I want to show" bgcolour=0x00000000 in=50 out=100`

Notes:

- dynamictext can not read text from a file like watermark can
- dynamictext requires pango or qtext producers to be installed